# How to escape single quotes in json string? JSON::ParserError Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I'm getting
`` /json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 783: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError) `` while trying to parse a json file in ruby. The problem was because there were some single quotes in one of the strings:

```
parsed = JSON.parse("{
  \"key1\":\"value1\",
  \"key2\":\"value2\",
  \"key3\":12345,
  \"key4\":\"''value4''\",
  }")
```

Is there a way to escape the single quotes in the strings without affect words like `don't`? The json is read from a file using `JSON.parse(file.get_input_stream.read)` that's why there are `\`.

Comment: You better show us raw file text;

Answer (score 3):

The single quotes aren't your problem, your problem is that you have a stray trailing comma:

```
parsed = JSON.parse("{
  \"key1\":\"value1\",
  \"key2\":\"value2\",
  \"key3\":12345,
  \"key4\":\"''value4''\",
}") #--------------------^ This should not be there.
```

JSON doesn't allow that comma so you don't actually have a JSON file.

You should figure out where the file came from and fix that tool to produce real JSON rather than the "looks mostly like JSON" that is currently being written to the file.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The problem wasn't the single quotes.